# How can I create memory management with a char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, char

I have to create a memory management program using a char array. The code I need to edit is as follows:

```
  char mem[65536];

  void initialize(void){
    // TODO 
  }

  void* allocate(int Size){
    // TODO
    return ((void*) 0);
  }

  void deallocate(void* Pointer){
    // TODO
  }

  // scan the memory returning the total free space
  int free(void){
    // TODO
    return 0;
  }
```

I am currently trying to use structs and store them in the char array, but that doesn't seem to be working out. The struct I am using is:

```
typedef struct Node{
    int size;
    int free;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
}Node;
```

I try to find the memory for the struct by:

```
Node *start = &mem;
```

Is there an error in the struct implementation, or should I be implementing something other than a struct to manage this?

EDIT:
Restrictions:
I have to store all data in the char array mem.
No global variables other than mem is allowed.

Comment: Storing the structs in the char array doesn't sound like a good idea... Putting a char pointer in the struct sounds much better to me.

Comment: I have to use the char array as the main storing method. I am not allowed to change that. And no other global variables are allowed.

Comment: ^Why use a `struct` then?

Comment: I have used this method before in a similar method and was familiar with it. There may be a better way to do it, but I couldn't think of how else to easily manage the char array.

Comment: The general idea is to allocate a char array that the user can use to store their memory, and you put that in the struct. The other fields in the struct are for your helper methods only (allocate, deallocate, etc..) and they manage the lifetime of the char array. Your char array is still your main storage method.

Comment: Make sure you align the "allocated" memory correctly

Comment: I've seen this! It's a simple problem with millions of ways to do it. I have to say pretty creative way.